# Non-ASCII characters in SubjectAlternativeName

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

I am trying to create `self-signed X509 certificates`, using `BouncyCastle.NET`. It seems to work in general, but I am failing for internationalised domain names that contain non-ASCII characters.

The following is a compact example of what I am doing. The unit test case for "`myDevice.abc.example.com`" succeeds, but it fails for other cases that include `non-ASCII` characters (like "`myDevice.äöü.example.com`").

```
[TestCase("myDevice.abc.example.com")]
[TestCase("myDevice.äöü.example.com")]  // western european
[TestCase("myDevice.ařa.example.com")]  // eastern european
[TestCase("mydevice.aデa.example.com")] // katakana
[Test]
public void IdnTest(string fqdn)
{
    #region Preparation
    ECKeyPairGenerator kpgen = new ECKeyPairGenerator();
    kpgen.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(new CryptoApiRandomGenerator()), Constants.SelectedRootKeySize));
    var caKeyPair = kpgen.GenerateKeyPair();
    var certKeyPair = kpgen.GenerateKeyPair();
    X509V3CertificateGenerator certGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
    certGenerator.SetSerialNumber(Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger.ProbablePrime(120, new Random()));
    IList oids = new ArrayList() { X509Name.OU };
    IList values = new ArrayList() { "Test" };
    certGenerator.SetIssuerDN(new X509Name(oids, values));
    certGenerator.SetNotBefore(DateTime.Now.Date);
    certGenerator.SetNotAfter(DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromDays(365));
    certGenerator.SetPublicKey(certKeyPair.Public);

    //var dnsString = new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerIA5String(fqdn, true);   //explicit validation would fail here
    //var dnsName = new GeneralName(dnsString, GeneralName.DnsName);
    var dnsName = new GeneralName(GeneralName.DnsName, fqdn);               //here I can create an GeneralName without validation failure
    GeneralNames subjectAltName = new GeneralNames(dnsName);
    certGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectAlternativeName, true, subjectAltName);

    ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory("sha256WithECDSA", caKeyPair.Private, new SecureRandom(new CryptoApiRandomGenerator()));
    Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate x509Certificate = certGenerator.Generate(signatureFactory);
    #endregion

    #region Verification
    var san = x509Certificate.GetSubjectAlternativeNames() as ArrayList;
    Assert.AreEqual(1, san.Count);
    var generalName = san[0] as System.Collections.ArrayList;
    Assert.AreEqual(GeneralName.DnsName, generalName[0]);
    object actual = generalName[1];
    Assert.AreEqual(fqdn, actual);
    #endregion
}
```

The final assertion fails, special characters in the string retrieved from the certificate are replaced by '?'.

Is this something that should work, am I doing something obvious wrong?

Comment: Have you tried debugging `fqdn` as it comes into the test? Then also checking `dnsName` then `subjectAltName` then `san` then `generalName`? Basically, you're trying to narrow down to which line of code corrupts one of the values. Then you can shorten the code in your question to just those lines.

Comment: The string looks good in the debugger up to and including the certGenerator.
When I retrieve the san back from the x509Certificate, I extract the generalName and no longer see the special characters.

Comment: Can you shorten your example code down to just those lines then? And it would be good to debug what is being created in the constructor of `new GeneralName(int tag, string name)`: Here's a link to the [source code for line 126](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/asn1/x509/GeneralName.cs#L126). It's either: `DerIA5String`, `DerObjectIdentifier`, `X509Name` or `DerOctetString` to find out if the accept special characters.

Comment: e.g. In `DerIA5String` there is optional validation which checks if the string is valid using: `foreach (char ch in str) { if (ch > 0x007f) { return false;`. Which means anything above 127 is invalid i.e. not ASCII.

Comment: I deliberately made the example as small as possible, but yet complete (as in: the code should be executable as is).

I had already looked at the source of the constructor of GeneralName; in the two commented lines of my example I tried to instantiate DerIA5STring with explicit validation. And that validation fails for non-ASCII characters.
Perhaps this means that I should escape the fqdn before creating a GeneralName? But escape according to what format?

(BTW: Thanks for your help!)

Comment: So when you inspect `GeneralName`, which instance was created for `this.obj` in the constructor?

Comment: dnsName.obj is an instance of DerIA5String, whose str property shows the correct string in the debugger, including non-ASCII characters. (because internally it uses the constructor without validation)

Comment: OK, so I started looking via `X509V3CertificateGenerator.AddExtension` -> `X509ExtensionsGenerator.AddExtension` -> `GeneralName.GetDerEncoded` -> `GeneralName.GetEncoded` -> `DerOutputStream(MemoryStream).WriteObject(GeneralName)` -> `MemoryStream().ToArray()` -> `byte[]` and I'm betting that's where it's become corrupted.

Comment: and in `DerIA5String` we have `byte[] GetOctets() { return Strings.ToAsciiByteArray(str)` which would corrupt strings which contain non-ASCII characters like yours. Seems like it's simply not supported.

Comment: Incedentally the docs do say: `/** Der IA5String object - this is an ascii string. */
public class DerIA5String`

Comment: The code should conform to [rfc 5280](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-7.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments by [DJDaveMark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344029/djdavemark) and [James K Polk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238704/james-k-polk) I found the answer: The domain name must be encoded according to [rfc 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-7.2) before creating the GeneralName:

```
var idn = new System.Globalization.IdnMapping();
idn.UseStd3AsciiRules = true;
idn.AllowUnassigned = false;
string encodedFqdn = idn.GetAscii(fqdn);
var dnsName = new GeneralName(GeneralName.DnsName, encodedFqdn);
```

And obviously it must be decoded after reading from the certificate:

```
var actualEncodedFqdn = generalName[1];
var actual = idn.GetUnicode(actualEncodedFqdn.ToString());
StringAssert.AreEqualIgnoringCase(fqdn, actual);
```